# Kali doesn't show power off button in system tab recently

Tags: kali-linux

I've recently installed GNOME and then uninstalled it. Maybe the problem is with that. Is there a way to show the power off button in System tab again?

Comment: Yes, very likely it's the cause. Kali is not intended as a desktop Linux so that kind of customizations tend to have unpredictable consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems resetting the DE does the trick and restores the hidden button.